# Is there a quick way to get the entire Google directory via Google drive api?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Now I need to get the directory structure of the entire Google drive and download the files according to this directory structure

Comment: Are you using Drive V2 or V3? What programming language are you using? Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following request to get the list of children for any parent folder. Dont forget to add the key param in the request url

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{folderId}/children
```

For more information on this please refer to the google developers page about [drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list).